# How to set Maven home path Bundled Maven as default [IntelliJ]

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

In settings Maven home path is always "Use Maven wapper" even if I set "Bundled (Maven 3)" in previous project.
How to set Maven home path Bundled Maven as default in IntelliJ?

Comment: Does your project have `mvnw` in the project root?

Comment: Please check what is selected in "File | New project setup | Settings/Preferences for new project".